# How can I fix AssertionFailure when using findByCustomerAndProduct in Spring Boot with Hibernate?

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, hibernate, orm

org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: force initializing collection loading
The CartItem Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart_items")
public class CartItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;
    private Integer quantity;
}
```

The CartItem Repository

```
public interface CartItemRepository extends CrudRepository<CartItem, Integer> {
    List<CartItem> findByCustomer(Customer customer);

    CartItem findByCustomerAndProduct(Customer customer, Product product);

    @Modifying
    void deleteByCustomerAndProduct(Customer customer, Product product);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE CartItem c SET c.quantity = ?1 WHERE c.product.id = ?2 AND c.customer.id = ?3")
    void updateQuantity(Integer quantity, Integer productid, Integer customerid);
}
```

Tring to use the findByCustomerAndProduct Gives an Assertion Error, same goes for the findByCustomer.
it's like i can't even work with the repository to retrieve cartItem, any operation just results in an AssertionError and says 'force initializing collection loading'

i have tried adding a @Query Annotation

```
@Query("some query that defines this operation")
CartItem findByCustomerAndProduct(Customer customer, Product product);
```

but that doesn't seem to make it right

Stack Trace;

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: force initializing collection loading
    at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:807) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:995) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:981) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.load(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4325) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4315) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:599) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:572) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1241) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1094) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntitySelectFetchInitializer.initializeInstance(EntitySelectFetchInitializer.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.load(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4325) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4315) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:599) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:572) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1241) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1094) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntitySelectFetchInitializer.initializeInstance(EntitySelectFetchInitializer.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:305) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:546) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.list(QuerySqmImpl.java:1032) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.getSingleResult(QuerySqmImpl.java:1062) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:193) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
```

Comment: This has been reported as Hibernate bug recently. Please check with the newest dependencies. Hope it helps.

Comment: I changed the spring boot version up to 3.1.0 and mysql driver. and i don't see the errors again. Thanks a ton